# When should one say "unikorno" instead of "unukornulo"?

Tags: word-choice

In serious, day-to-day discussions about the existence and eating habits of unicorns - discussions which are common, I'm sure - should one say *unikorno* or *unukornulo*?

Comment: Common indeed. I read an article of SO today comparing centaur cavalry to traditional men-on-a-horse cavalry, discussing who would be superior. I would assume _unikorno_ to be understandable, though I don't know any languages where the native word is much different. It's _Einhorn_ in German.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably never. I had never heard the word *unikorno* before and its definition in PIV is simply *unukornulo*.

Answer (score 1):

*Unukornulo* is the normal word, and was chosen by Kabe in his *Elektitaj Fabeloj de la Fratoj Grimm* (1906).

However, there are various traditions considering one-horned beasts (Wikipedia lists the *al-mi'raj, camahueto, indrik, monoceros, qilin, shadhavar,* and *sin-you*) and so in formal contexts it might be advisable to use *unikorno*. And obviously that word is also easier to pronounce.